# How to add preloader to each section/div in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a snippet on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/VwLRGZK) that adds a loader until the content is fully loaded.

```js
// makes sure the whole site is loaded
 jQuery(window).load(function() {
        // will first fade out the loading animation
    jQuery("#status").fadeOut();
        // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
    jQuery("#preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
  
})
```

```css
#preloader  {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     background-color: #fff;
     z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
 }

#status  {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     background-image: url(http://opengraphicdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/loader64.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
 }

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex > div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  background: red;
}

.right {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
  <div id="status"></div>
</div>

<img src="##">

<div class="flex">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of adding one loader to the entire page, how can I add a loader to each div box?

I saw another reference [here](https://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/) which I am struggling to implement and [here is how far I got with my codepen](https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/XWbGPvN).

Comment: How fare did you go in trying to implement?

Comment: I would have to rollback my snippet because the current one was my last attempt.
Will actually create a new one.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy there you have another snippet in my edited question. I thought it was the image referencing but still, the loader does not show

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264196/css-loaders-render-multiple-on-a-page

Answer (score 0):

The thing about this is, that your example uses the load event of the window. When you want to have a spinner for a div, you will have to define under what condition the div is "ready" and the spinner should fade out.
Is it ready when it is rendered? Is it ready when all resources are loaded?

The bit easier way would be to just add spinner to images. So give your img tags in the src attribute eg. a spinner.gif and add a data-src attribute to the tag.

```
<img src="spinner.gif" data-src="your-picture-to-be-loaded.jpg">
```

Then you can start loading the picture via javascript and replace the spinner with the downloaded picture. For this you could use a new Image object:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
$(img).on('load', function() {
  imgTag.src = img.src;
});
img.src = data-src-value-of-your-img-tag;
```

All this done in a loop over all img tags that have a data-src attribute.

Another approach for your DIV-Example would be to load the contents of the div via ajax and just load a dummy content like:

```
<div data-load="/some-html-to-be-rendered.html">
    <img src="spinner.gif" alt="loading">
</div>
```

and then replace the contents of the div with the loaded html from your data-load attribute.

Comment: I meant something like in this sample here: https://smallenvelop.com/demo/image-loading/